# How to use cut_width with quasiquotation within ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-evaluation

I would like to make this code into a function:

```
diamonds %>%
ggplot() +
geom_boxplot(aes(x = carat, y = price, group = cut_width(carat, 0.1)))
```

Output of the code:
[The resulting ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCMRD.png)

My attempt is:

```
pair_relationship_plot = function(df, x, y) {
  quo_x = enquo(x)
  quo_y = enquo(y)

  df %>%
    ggplot(aes_(x = quo_x, y = quo_y)) +     
    geom_boxplot(aes_(group = cut_width(enquo(x), 0.1)))
}

pair_relationship_plot(diamonds, carat, price)
```

However, the cut_width inside the geom_boxplot() was giving me `Error in cut_width(enquo(x), 5) : 'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

If I change the code to `cut_width(~x, 0.1)` it still produced the same error.

How do I make the function work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with the inputs to your function being character strings, you can do this easily by using the `aes_string` function with ggplot2 which accepts aesthetics as strings. The below function does what you want

```
make_boxplot = function(df, x_ax, y_ax){
group_text = paste0("cut_width(",x_ax,", 0.1)")

df %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x=x_ax, y=y_ax)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes_string(group = group_text))
}
```

And the function call to get the same output as your example graph would be `make_boxplot(diamonds, "carat", "price")`

Or if you want to save a few keystrokes and really don't want to have character string inputs for your function, you can just use `deparse(substitute())` inside the function. ie

```
make_boxplot = function(df, x_ax, y_ax){
  x_ax=deparse(substitute(x_ax))
  y_ax=deparse(substitute(y_ax))
  group_text = paste0("cut_width(",x_ax,", 0.1)")

  df %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x=x_ax, y=y_ax)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes_string(group = group_text))
}
```

And now you can just call `make_boxplot(diamonds, carat, price)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I tried reading the doc but I don't really get how quote() differs from substitute(), or how they are different from quo() and !! in dplyr package. I've read the vignette but I got even more confused. Is there another reading material that may be able to explain it in a different/clearer way?